# How to fix "Syntax error or access violation: 1064"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'am new in laravel world. After php artisan migrate -seed command, I got the error
MariaDB 10.4.6
PHP 7.3

The problem with SQL code shouldn't be

```
DB::table('settings')->insert($typi_settings);
$max = DB::table('settings')->max('id');
DB::select(DB::raw("select setval('typicms_settings_id_seq', $max)"));
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''typicms_settings_id_seq', 15)' at line 1 (SQL: select setval('typicms_settings_id_seq', 15))

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing a `select` by calling the `select` method on the QueryBuilder, try this instead:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("setval('typicms_settings_id_seq', $max)"));
```